QgsRasterBandComboBox/ ComboBox unable to process raster calculator
I'm creating a plugin to calculate NDVI and NDWI indices in QGIS v3.36.2. I have successfully created the GUI as below and successfully loaded the layers and bands of the layers. The data I am using is multiband landsat 8 data.

The select input file using QgsMapLayerComboBox and the select band using QgsRasterBandComboBox. I use the signal when the input file changes, the select band will also change as shown below.

However, when I want to process to NDVI / NDWI when calling data based on the selected band displays an error
TypeError: int cannot be converted to qgis._core.QgsRasterLayer in this context on line ras_nir.raster = self.dlg.NIR_band.currentData()
Here's the full script I used
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
/***************************************************************************
 GenerateIndex
                                 A QGIS plugin
 this plugin to generate NDVI and NDWI indices
 Generated by Plugin Builder: http://g-sherman.github.io/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/
                              -------------------
        begin                : 2024-06-12
        git sha              : $Format:%H$
        copyright            : (C) 2024 by Imron 
        email                : xxxxx@gmail.com
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
"""
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QFileDialog
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import *


# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *

# Import the code for the dialog
from .Generate_NDVI_NDWI_dialog import GenerateIndexDialog
import os.path


class GenerateIndex:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value("locale/userLocale")[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir, "i18n", "GenerateIndex_{}.qm".format(locale)
        )

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr("&Generate NDVI NDWI")

        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = None

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate("GenerateIndex", message)

    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None,
    ):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToRasterMenu(self.menu, action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ":/plugins/Generate_NDVI_NDWI/icon.png"
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(""),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow(),
        )

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True

    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginRasterMenu(self.tr("&Generate NDVI NDWI"), action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)

    def NDVI(self):
        entries = []
        output = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
        # nir band
        ras_nir = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        ras_nir.ref = "nir_band"
        ras_nir.raster = self.dlg.NIR_band.currentData()
        ras_nir.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(ras_nir)
        # red band
        ras_red = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        ras_red.ref = "red_band"
        ras_red.raster = self.dlg.red_band.currentData()
        ras_red.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(ras_red)

        calculate = QgsRasterCalculator(
            '("nir_band" - "red_band") / ("nir_band" + "red_band")',
            output,
            "GTiff",
            self.dlg.NIR_band.currentData().extent(),
            self.dlg.NIR_band.currentData().width(),
            self.dlg.NIR_band.currentData().height(),
            entries,
        )
        calculate.processCalculation()
        self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage(
            "NDVI Successfully", level=Qgis.Success, duration=5
        )

    def NDWI(self):
        entries = []
        output = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
        # nir band
        ras_nir = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        ras_nir.ref = "green_band"
        ras_nir.raster = self.dlg.green_band.currentData()
        ras_nir.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(ras_nir)
        # red band
        ras_red = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        ras_red.ref = "nir_band"
        ras_red.raster = self.dlg.NIR_band.currentData()
        ras_red.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(ras_red)

        calculate = QgsRasterCalculator(
            '("green_band" - "nir_band") / ("green_band" + "nir_band")',
            output,
            "GTiff",
            self.dlg.green_band.currentData().extent(),
            self.dlg.green_band.currentData().width(),
            self.dlg.green_band.currentData().height(),
            entries,
        )
        calculate.processCalculation()
        self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage(
            "NDVI Successfully", level=Qgis.Success, duration=5
        )

    def select_output_file(self):
        filename, _filter = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self.dlg, "Select output file ", "", "*.tif"
        )
        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)

    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = GenerateIndexDialog()
            self.dlg.pushButton_Output.clicked.connect(self.select_output_file)

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            if self.dlg.radioButton_ndvi.isChecked():
                self.NDVI()
            elif self.dlg.radioButton_ndwi.isChecked():
                self.NDWI()


You are mixing up band number and raster layer when creating the raster calculator entries. You are setting a band number (integer) as the QgsRasterCalculatorEntry.raster attribute, which needs to be a QgsRasterLayer object; hence the error you are getting.
You should retrieve the current band (an integer) from your QgsRasterBandComboBox for each input band and set that as the QgsRasterCalculatorEntry.bandNumber attribute instead of hard coding an integer e.g.
ras_red.bandNumber = self.dlg.red_band.currentBand()

For the QgsRasterCalculatorEntry.raster attribute you should retrieve the currentLayer() from your QgsMapLayerComboBox.
Something like:
ras_nir.raster = self.dlg.lyr_combo_box.currentLayer()

Here is a basic example in a QDialog sub-class.
from osgeo import gdal

class NDVIDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NDVIDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 500, 300)
        self.lyr_lbl = QLabel('Select input layer', self)
        self.lyr_cb = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self)
        self.lyr_cb.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.RasterLayer)
        self.red_band_lbl = QLabel('Select red band', self)
        self.red_band_cb = QgsRasterBandComboBox(self)
        self.nir_band_lbl = QLabel('Select NIR band', self)
        self.nir_band_cb = QgsRasterBandComboBox(self)
        self.output_lbl = QLabel('Output file', self)
        self.output_widget = QgsFileWidget(self)
        self.output_widget.setStorageMode(QgsFileWidget.SaveFile)
        self.output_widget.setFilter("*.tif")
        self.btn_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lyr_lbl, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lyr_cb, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.red_band_lbl, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.red_band_cb, 1, 1, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.nir_band_lbl, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.nir_band_cb, 2, 1, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.output_lbl, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.output_widget, 3, 1, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_box, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        
        self.set_layer(self.lyr_cb.currentLayer())
        self.lyr_cb.layerChanged.connect(self.set_layer)
        self.btn_box.rejected.connect(lambda: self.close())
        self.btn_box.accepted.connect(self.calculate_ndvi)
        
    def set_layer(self, current_lyr):
        if not current_lyr:
            return()
        if current_lyr.type() == QgsMapLayerType.Raster:
            for cb in self.findChildren(QgsRasterBandComboBox):
                cb.setLayer(current_lyr)
                
    def calculate_ndvi(self):
        results = ['Calculation successful',
                    'Error creating output data file',
                    'Error reading input layer',
                    'User canceled calculation',
                    'Error parsing formula',
                    'Error allocating memory for result',
                    'Invalid band number for input',
                    'Error occurred while performing calculation']
        
        r_lyr = self.lyr_cb.currentLayer()

        entries = []

        # Red Band
        b1_entry = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        b1_entry.ref = 'red_band'
        b1_entry.raster = r_lyr
        b1_entry.bandNumber = self.red_band_cb.currentBand()
        entries.append(b1_entry)

        # NIR Band
        b2_entry = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        b2_entry.ref = 'nir_band'
        b2_entry.raster = r_lyr
        b2_entry.bandNumber = self.nir_band_cb.currentBand()
        entries.append(b2_entry)

        expression = '("nir_band"-"red_band")/("nir_band"+"red_band")'
        output = self.output_widget.filePath()
        bbox = r_lyr.extent()
        crs = r_lyr.crs()
        width = r_lyr.width()
        height = r_lyr.height()

        calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression,
                                   output,
                                   'GTiff',
                                   bbox,
                                   crs,
                                   width,
                                   height,
                                   entries)
                                   
        res = calc.processCalculation()
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'NDVI Calculation', results[res], QMessageBox.Ok)
        calc = None
        del calc
        entries.clear()

dlg = NDVIDialog()
dlg.show()


